# Contents persistence in google script "blob"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm putting togheter some lines of code in Google scripts. The important piece is (consider true the fact that I have a good `mySpreadsheet` with contents, also `source` and `folder` are set):

```
    [...]
    var mySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(source.getId()).makeCopy("test", folder))

  [...]
  var sheet = mySpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

  sheet.clear();

  //email, obj, msg are string set before
  sendPdf(mySpreadsheet, pdfName, email, obj, msg);

}

function sendPdf(sheet, pdfName, email, object, message) {

  //save to pdf
  var pdfFile = sheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);

  // Send the freshly constructed email 
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, object message, {attachments:[pdfFile]});
}
```

The script works, it means that the script creates the pdf and attach it to the email.
I expected, after cleaning the (only) sheet of the file, to receive an empty pdf.
`mySpreadsheet` is empty, but the pdf attached contains all the contents copied from source. Where these data came from? Where are they "stored" when the sheet is being cleared? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In your situation, you want to receive the Spreadsheet using `sheet.clear()` for the 1st sheet as an attachment file of an email.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification point:

- Although I'm not sure about your whole script, after `sheet.clear()` is run, it seems that the Spreadsheet is not saved. I thought that this is the reason of your issue.

  - By saving the Spreadsheet after using `sheet.clear()`, the blob can be retrieved from the updated Spreadsheet.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows and test it again.

From:

```
sheet.clear();
```

To:

```
sheet.clear();
SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Added
```

#### Reference:

- [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: With flush() you saved my day. Thank you so much!

Comment: @marcoresk Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.